# How to change object's properties without having infinite loop in Vue JS watcher?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have an an Array of Objects like this :

```
    let tree = [
    {
       task: "Some Task",
       spentTime : 2, 
       subTasks: {
          task: "Some Sub Task",
          spentTime: 1,
             subTasks:{
                task:"Some sub sub task",
                spentTime:30
             }
       }
    }
 ]
```

As you can see here i have this type of tree structure and i am displaying that some kind of nested accordion. So every node has a input box which has 2 way binding with spentTime property `( using v-model )`.

Now if i type in any of the node's input. i need to do some operation on these spentTime values and re-populate Or insert different values in the same object.

Here i was thinking doing deep `watch`. But i think this will cause infinite loop because i am changing the same object and assigning value back and it triggers `watch` again :)

What i can do if i want to trigger a function on input change and put different values back in the same object.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please define the user experience with complete disregard of technical implementation? What should happen to `spentTime` of parent when `spentTime` of child changes? And what should happen to `spentTime` of children when `spentTime` of parent changes? What's the expected relation between them and which value should be prevalent when they don't add up?

Comment: Okay. If i change any spent time i need to update parents spent time. Basically just add up to parents spent time. To calculate this i am using post order tree traversal. is that you asked?)

Comment: Yes. Let's say you hard-coded a parent spent time. It says `12`. But its children add up to `2`. And you change one of the children and they now add up to `4`. Do you want to override the initial `12` with `4`? You don't seem to have a technical implementation issue. It's more of a requirements definition issue. As long as you know what should happen, it's easy to do. :). We're getting back to my initial question: *"Which value should be prevalent in case of conflicts?"*

Comment: Yes. exactly. i have a function which traverse the full tree and calculate required values and put it back. But then how do i listen for change ?

Comment: Does *"Yes"* mean *"Yes, `12` should be overridden with `4`"*? If you think it's relevant, provide the function you have. Eventually, create a [mcve] even if it creates a  stack overflow. At least we can see the required logic.

Comment: Yes ) and parents input also should be disabled,  if we change children value.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210614/discussion-between-tao-and-truecode).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr**

The clean solution, based on @djiss suggestion, and which correctly bubbles up to top parent, using `$set` and `watch`, is here: 
https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-kilby-yqy9v
What's below is the initial answer/logic, which uses `$emit` and the task 'key' to move the update in the parent.

---

<strike>In Vue you can't modify the child directly. I mean, you **can**, but you *shouldn't*. When you do it, Vue warns you about it informing you the change you just made will be overridden as soon as the parent changes.</strike>

The only options are to use state to manage the single source of trouth for your app (Vuex or a simple Vue object), or you call the parent telling it: *"Change this particular child with this particular value"*. And you simply listen to changes coming from parent.

Which is what I did here:

```js
const task = {
  task: "Some Task",
  spentTime: 2,
  subTasks: [{
    task: "Some Sub Task",
    spentTime: 1,
    subTasks: [{
      task: "Some sub sub task",
      spentTime: 30
    }, {
      task: "Some other sub sub task",
      spentTime: 12
    }]
  }]
};

Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.component('Task', {
  template: `
  <div>
    <h2>{{task.task}} ({{spentTime}})</h2>
    <div v-if="hasTasks">
      <Task v-for="(t, k) in task.subTasks" :key="k" :task="t" @fromChild="fromChild" :tid="k"/>
    </div>
    <input v-else v-model="localTime" type="number" @input="updateParent(localTime)">
  </div>
  `,
  props: {
    task: {
      type: Object,
      required: true
    },
    tid: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0
    }
  },
  data: () => ({
    localTime: 0
  }),
  mounted() {
    this.updateParent(this.spentTime);
  },
  computed: {
    spentTime() {
      return this.hasTasks ? this.subtasksTotal : this.task.spentTime;
    },
    subtasksTotal() {
      return this.task.subTasks.map(t => t.spentTime).reduce(this.sum, 0)
    },
    hasTasks() {
      return !!(this.task.subTasks && this.task.subTasks.length);
    }
  },
  methods: {
    fromChild(time, task) {
      this.task.subTasks[task].spentTime = time;
      this.updateParent(this.spentTime);
    },
    updateParent(time) {
      this.$emit("fromChild", Number(time), this.tid);
      this.localTime = this.spentTime;
    },
    sum: (a, b) => a + b
  },
  watch: {
    "task.spentTime": function() {
      this.localTime = this.task.spentTime;
    }
  }
});
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: () => ({
    task
  }),
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <Task :task="task" :tid="0" />
</div>
```

It will consume any tree you throw at it, provided it has the same structure. The logic is: show the input if no subtasks or calculate from subtasks otherwise.
Obviously, you can change that to fit your needs.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I will try it. will let you know.

Comment: @True, based on djss's suggestion, I was able to greatly simplify the solution. You have the simplified version, using `$set()` in the sandbox.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar reactivity issues with Vue.js
Try to use Vue.set or this.$set to save any changes to your array :

```
this.$set(this.someObject, 'b', 2)
```

- You can read more about Vue set [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set).
- You can read more information about Vue reactivity [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html).

Comment: How does this solve the recursivity problem? How do you know if you're in a level 1 or level 4 item? Could you provide a working example?

Comment: I might have misunderstood the question, I would not use watch at all, I would set the new variable in the Object using this.$set using a custom event emitted by the component.

Comment: You haven't. It does work with `$set`. Pretty cool. I was able to greatly simplify my [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-kilby-yqy9v). I'm wondering if I can ditch `localTime` and use `task.spentTime` as `v-model`.

Comment: Kinda. I can use it as `v-model` through a computed, where the setter si `this.$set()`. Quite cool.

Comment: However, without `watch` on `task.spentTime` the change doesn't bubble up. A change in level 3 will only change level 2. So the watcher is needed, unfortunately. It's still much cleaner and lighter. If you think it can be simplified further, feel free to clone my sandbox and share you thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this headache before, and I did solve/ cheat on it with deep `watch` and [Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15) `_.cloneDeep` and `_.isEqual`.

Inside your child component, create your own data `componentTask`. You will `watch` your `componentTask` and your `prop`. Every time they change, compare them using `_.isEqual`. When `componentTask` changes, emit an event to its parent.

SubTask:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <input type="text" v-model="componentTask.task">
        <input type="number" min="0" v-model.number="componentTask.spentTime">
        <SubTask v-if="task.subTasks" @task-change="handleTaskChange" :task="task.subTasks" />
    </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
    import {Vue, Component, Prop, Watch} from 'vue-property-decorator'
    import {Task} from "@/components/Test/Test";
    import _ from "lodash";

    @Component
    export default class SubTask extends Vue {
        @Prop() task!: Task;

        componentTask: Task | undefined = this.task;

        @Watch('task', {deep: true, immediate: true})
        onTaskChange(val: Task, oldVal: Task) {
            if (_.isEqual(this.componentTask, val))
                return;

            this.componentTask = _.cloneDeep(val);
        }

        @Watch('componentTask', {deep: true, immediate: true})
        onComponentTaskChange(val: Task, oldVal: Task) {
            if (_.isEqual(val, this.task))
                return;

            this.$emit("task-change");
        }

        handleTaskChange(subTasks: Task){
            this.componentTask = subTasks;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Parent class:

```
<template>
    <div style="margin-top: 400px">
        <h1>Parent Task</h1>
        <br>
        <div style="display: flex;">
            <div style="width: 200px">
                <h4>task</h4>
                <p>{{task.task}}</p>
                <p>{{task.spentTime}}</p>
                <br>
            </div>
            <div style="width: 200px">
                <h4>task.subTasks</h4>
                <p>{{task.subTasks.task}}</p>
                <p>{{task.subTasks.spentTime}}</p>
                <br>
            </div>
            <div style="width: 200px">
                <h4>task.subTasks.subTasks</h4>
                <p>{{task.subTasks.subTasks.task}}</p>
                <p>{{task.subTasks.subTasks.spentTime}}</p>
                <br>
            </div>
        </div>
            <SubTask :task="task" @task-change="handleTaskChange"/>
    </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
    import {Vue, Component, Prop} from 'vue-property-decorator'
    import SubTask from "@/components/Test/SubTask.vue";
    import {defaultTask, Task} from "@/components/Test/Test";

    @Component({
        components: {SubTask}
    })
    export default class Test extends Vue {
        task: Task = defaultTask;

        handleTaskChange(task: Task) {
            this.task = task;
        }
    }

</script>
```

Defined interface:

```
export interface Task {
    task: string;
    spentTime: number;
    subTasks?: Task;
}

export const defaultTask: Task = {
    task: "Some Task",
    spentTime : 2,
    subTasks: {
        task: "Some Sub Task",
        spentTime: 1,
        subTasks:{
            task:"Some sub sub task",
            spentTime:30
        }
    }
};
```